# Not able to login into liferay portal using LDAP credentials

Tags: authentication, configuration, active-directory, ldap, liferay

I have followed the steps that you have mentioned [in this blog](https://www.liferay.com/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/16387690). For the base dn they have given something like 'Base DN - dc=,dc=', but I gave something like 'ecompany.local'. Since I am not the admin of the ldap, I gave the principal as the my ldap id and credentials my ldap password . When I clicked on test connection, I got the popup window that shows "Liferay has successfully connected to the LDAP server" .

Next, I followed the steps regarding Authentication Search Filter, Import search filter and User Mapping. But when I Clicked on test ldap users, popup window showed that there are no users currently(this might be because I do not have the ldap admin credentials. )

SAVED the configuration.

Went to control panel --> Authenticaion --> LDAP, checked enabled, import enabled and import on start up enabled.

Restarted the server.

Clicked on sign in. Fed in the ldap login credentials, and I am not able to login using the ldap credentials. But can login using Liferay's id and password. Why?

Answer (score 0):

One thing to be sure is that the password encryption rule is setup right for your LDAP server.

In `portal.properties` you can read this:

```
#
# Set either bind or password-compare for the LDAP authentication method.
# Bind is preferred by most vendors so that you don't have to worry about
# encryption strategies.
#
ldap.auth.method=bind
#ldap.auth.method=password-compare

# Set the password encryption to use for comparing passwords during import
# and to use for encrypting passwords during export. Comparing passwords
# during import will only be used when the property "ldap.auth.method" is
# set to password-compare. If the encryption is set to NONE, which is the
# default value, passwords are considered as plain text. The SHA-512
# algorithm is currently unsupported.
#
#ldap.auth.password.encryption.algorithm=BCRYPT
#ldap.auth.password.encryption.algorithm=MD2
#ldap.auth.password.encryption.algorithm=MD5
ldap.auth.password.encryption.algorithm=NONE
#ldap.auth.password.encryption.algorithm=SHA
#ldap.auth.password.encryption.algorithm=SHA-256
#ldap.auth.password.encryption.algorithm=SHA-384
#ldap.auth.password.encryption.algorithm=SSHA
#ldap.auth.password.encryption.algorithm=UFC-CRYPT
```

Comment: Am i suppossed to add these to the portal.properties file?

Comment: You have to create an override setting through a new file portal-ext.properties,  see developers tutorials

Comment: Hi.. I did add these properties in the portal-ext.properties file. Restarted the server. Tried to sign in using the ldap login credentials. but it was unsuccessful.

Comment: You need to understand your ldap, use Jxplorer app to connect and view ldap mapping and settings